# Oracle EBS with Backbase portal integration

Tags: oracle-apps, oracleapplications, backbase-portal

I was working with Oracle e business suite, e commerce modules, iStore etc. I want to integrate Backbase portal to add new look and feel to my application. I just want to know whether we can integrate EBS or iStore with Backbase portal.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Backbase can be integrated with legacy systems using the integration service that comes out of box from backbase.

But the driver for Backbase to best suit your business needs is:

- Do you need Portals and Page management?
- Do you need User Management?
- Do you need Content Management on the the fly?
- Do you need User Personalization?

If these are your drivers for a WebApp Backbase would be one of the most suitable candidates.

If these are not your major drivers you can go with Simple Angular based web applications.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Backbase Portal comes with an integration layer based on Apache Camel witch supports integration to these services out of the box.

It is also possible to create a PTC data provider that integrates with the ESB. Basically, if you have an

Comment: Can you share some resource or material where I can learn how to integrate Backbase with third party microservices from scratch? In my case I do not have access to Backbase server as it is hosted by another vendor. I only need to focus on managing my middle tier. Simple demo app in Spring microservice would be a great help.

Comment: Well, since Backbase is a closed source it's documentation is not available outside.
Best approach will be to create an account at https://community.backbase.com and read the documentation available.

Alternatively, Join us (Xebia IT Architects) we will integrate it together. :-D

Answer (score 0):

Yes, We Can!.

We can integrate backbase portal virtually with any application since it comes integrated with Apache Camel.

As per [the documentation here](https://blogs.oracle.com/stevenChan/entry/introducing_oracle_e_business_suite) EBS has exposed APIs in format of REST.

To use the same in a widget, you may need to create a route from [restlet](http://camel.apache.org/restlet.html) to [http](http://camel.apache.org/http.html)

Comment: Can you share some resource or material where I can learn how to integrate Backbase with third party microservices from scratch? In my case I do not have access to Backbase server as it is hosted by another vendor. I only need to focus on managing my middle tier. Simple demo app in Spring microservice would be a great help.

Comment: I suggest checking community.backbase.com for more details, Tag me over there and I can help: mohit <DOT> kanwar <At> xebia.com